# Convert Yii1 code to Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I am a newbie in Yii framework and I am trying to convert a Yii1 code to Yii2.

I know that there is no CDbCriteria class in Yii2, so for example, for the following Yii1 code:

```
$criOrder = new CDbCriteria();            
$criOrder->order = 'CRI_PresentationOrder';
$criModels = Criteria::model()->findAll($criOrder);
```

I have produced the Yii2 statement:

```
$criModels = Criteria::find()->orderBy('CRI_PresentationOrder')->all();
```

But I have some problems trying to find the right way to convert this one:

```
$crvCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
$crvCriteria->with = array('aCRCRV', 'aCRCRV.cRVCRI');
$crvCriteria->together = true;
$crvCriteria->condition = 'ACR_APP_Id = :appId';
$crvCriteria->params = array(':appId'=>$id);
$crvCriteria->order = 'cRVCRI.CRI_PresentationOrder';
$crvModels = ApplicantCriteriaValue::model()->findAll($crvCriteria);
```

especially regarding the 'with', 'together' and 'params' attributes.

Any ideas/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: please show the flat query based on your converting code ..

Comment: **SELECT** *
**FROM** ApplicantCriteriaValue **INNER JOIN** CriteriaValue **ON** ACV_CRV_Id=CRV_Id
**INNER JOIN** Criteria **ON** CRV_CRI_Id=CRI_Id
**WHERE** ACV_APP_Id = :appId
**ORDER BY** CRI_PresentationOrder

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your ApplicantCriteriaValue table has a model named ApplicantCriteriaValue then should be

```
$criModels = ApplicantCriteriaValue::find()
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_criteria_value',
            'tbl_criteria_value.ACV_CRV_Id =ApplicantCriteriaValue.CRV_Id')  
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_criteria',
            'tbl_criteria.CRV_CRI_Id =ApplicantCriteriaValue.CRV_Id')     
  ->orderBy('CRI_PresentationOrder')->all();
```

Comment: Thank you! What about the Yii1 'together' attribute?

Comment: in  yii2  you don't need together  .. eventualy you should eval relations for this see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html  and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data